# Chartist line chart each node on click

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

At the moment I have a simply Chartist line chart, and I can easily add an on click mechanism to it using:

```
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
    if(data.type === 'line') {
        data.element._node.onclick = function (){window.location = "https://www.google.com"}
    }
});
```

However this adds the `onclick` to the whole line.

I wish to add the on click mechanism to each data point on the line chart instead.

For example, if my line chart data is:

```
[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]
```

I wish for there to be a separate on click mechanism for each x axis data point, if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event for `data.type = point`

```
if (data.type === "point") {
    data.element._node.onclick = function() {
      window.location = "https://www.google.com/?q=" + data.value.y
    }
}
```

Here's the jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/zv8t7o6p/12/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this with a hover feature? (no matter where they hover in the y axis?) And so they don't need to just hit the point itself?

Comment: Yes, but I would not recommend it as it will open multiple pages on mouse movement.

Comment: Apologies I don't mean trigger on hover, I mean, is there a way to see if you are hovering over an x axis point (at any y co-ord) and clicking anywhere on that grid line? I want to be able to click anywhere on the y axis above an x co-ord